# Textbook confusion with CMRR and transconductance mismatch

Tags: differential

I am just looking for an explanation on how a 2% mismatch in aspect ratio (W/L) results in a 1% error in transconductance paramater g_m (I can't figure out latex right now). The textbook conveniently skips over how they arrived at this value.
I have been struggling over this solution for most of the day and to no avail. When I looked up a similar solution online for a textbook question in the back of the book, the author also skipped explanation of this. So now I am here, as a last resort.

[image]

As Brian pointed out in the comments, my main question is essentially: Why does using this specific equation work (9.89 in picture), but using $$g_{m}=\mu _{n}C_{ox}\frac{W}{L}V_{OV}$$ does not.

Comment: Formula is right there. Note sqrt(1.02) is just about 1.01.

Comment: If this is the case, why can't I use the equation: $$g_{m}=\mu _{n}C_{ox}\frac{W}{L}V_{OV}$$ Shouldn't this give similar results? Why does using the square root version with drain current magically give the right value?

Comment: Why wasn't that part of the question? (extracting this new formula from same book; also name/link the book)

Comment: The book is Sedra/Smith Microelectronics 7th edition in the differential amplifier chapter. I didn’t initially ask that because I didn’t know it needed to be from that equation. I figured the author just selected that equation just because it’s used often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two equations subtly encode different assumptions and do not contradict each other. When you use \$g_{m}=\mu _{n}C_{ox}\frac{W}{L}V_{OV}\$ to estimate the error in \$g_m\$, you are looking for the effect of errors in the shape ratio on the transconductance, *with overdrive voltage held constant* (and thus drain current varying as the shape ratio varies).

On the other hand, when you use \$g_m = \sqrt{2(\mu_n C_{ox})\left(\frac{W}{L}\right)I_d}\$, you are looking for the effect of shape ratio on transconductance, with drain current held constant (and overdrive voltage varying to make this happen, e.g. in a structure with feedback). Since the square root of 1.02 is approximately 1.01 as already pointed out in the comments, we get the 1% error which is expected.

This equation here is useful in many scenarios where the drain current is held constant (e.g. in the scenario given in the text, as well as in a common source amplifier biased with a current source, and with the gate voltage's DC bias established through feedback).